# Color detection in opencv (python)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, hsv

I'm trying to make a  mask of all green pixels and one of all yellow pixels using the inrange function. The big trouble I have is finding the correct HSV values for both colors because they seem to overlap.
The following picture ([green circle](http://nl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=160yib4&s=8#.VHNWTIuG91Y)) should detect the green circle only in the yellow mask, this picture ([yellow square](http://nl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=akwihl&s=8#.VHNWxouG91Y)) must do the opposite (only yellow) but i cannot seem to seperate them.

I use the following HSV values

```
#Yellow
lower_yellow = np.array([20, 20, 20], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_yellow = np.array([35, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)

#Green
lower_green = np.array([24, 40, 40], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_green = np.array([60, 255, 120], dtype=np.uint8)
```

I hope anyone can help